# How do I make a chrome homescreen web app window resize height when the soft keyboard opens?

Tags: android, google-chrome, responsive-design, homescreen

I have set up meta tags in a web application to allow android chrome users to add the application to their homescreen.

I used the chrome 31+ support.

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

When a form input is focused, the soft keyboard appears.

In the chrome browser application, the window size is reduced vertically to compensate for the soft keyboard.

In the home screen application the window does not resize vertically, so when the soft keyboard is open, the user needs to close the soft keyboard in order to view content or inputs hidden by the soft keyboard. I am unable to scroll to the bottom of the view while the soft keyboard is open.

EDIT: Related issue logged here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8132

Comment: I'm curious about this too as I have the same problem at the moment.

Comment: I have now experienced the same behaviour on a native webview so it may be connected.

Answer (score 0):

Use this meta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Does this reduce the size of the webview window when the soft keyboard appears?